# Bigger is Greater Problem - how to optimise the solution

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

**Problem**

> Given a word, create a new word by swapping some or all of its
>   characters. This new word must meet two criteria:
>
> - It must be greater than the original word It must be the smallest word.
> - It must be the smallest word that meets the first condition

Please see the the full problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bigger-is-greater)

**My effort**

I am trying to solve this challenge but don't want to use a permutation.

The below code works well for a small piece of test data, however it cannot pass `100000` cases. Could anyone help to provide some suggestions to optimise the below code:

```
t=int(raw_input())
for _ in range(t):
    s=list(raw_input().strip())#change to list
    pos = -1#check pos, if pos is bigger, it's smallest bigger lexilogical, so only choose big pos
    i_temp=0

    for i in reversed(range(len(s))):
        for j in reversed(range(i)):
            if s[i]>s[j]: #last letter is bigger than previous, in this case , we can swap to previous one, and found bigger one.
                if j>pos:
                    pos=j#new place
                    i_temp=i
                    break
                if j<pos:
                    break #already found good one
            if i<pos:
                break #already found good one
    if  pos>=0:                                              
        s_tmp=s[pos]                                          
        s[pos]=s[i_temp]                                      
        s[i_temp]=s_tmp                                          
        s1 = s[pos+1:]                  #get string for smallest   
        s1.sort()                                                
        print ("".join(s[:pos+1]+s1))            
    else:                                                        
        print ("no answer")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider moving this Question to Stack Exchange's [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) website, as your code indeed works, and simply requires optimization. Refer: [Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261841/1248974)

Comment: Well, just think about it. How can you move the characters in `w` to obtain a lexicographically greater string `s`? By definition if `w < s` then either `w[0] < s[0]` or `w[0] == s[0] and w[1:] < s[1:]`. How can you make sure that `w[0] < s[0]`? Well: if `s[0]` is the biggest character in the string then you are sure to obtain that comparison, or at least obtain `w[0] == s[0]` and proceed recursively... continue this reasoning and in the end you'll discover that the answer is `''.join(sorted(text, reversed=True))`

Comment: A quick thought: can this problem be solved by using divide and conquer paradigm?

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is right, so I'll try to help.

Step1: You're iterating in reverse looking for a case where a[i] < a[i+n], then you know you have a solution. 
Step2: Then you paste everything (the prefix, the character, and the sorted suffix junk.)

Just make it easy on yourself: find the solution point first, then compute the output. Don't try to track the variables needed for step 2 in step 1. Step 2 is only going to get called once per string:

```
def f(w):
    best = ''
    for i in range(len(w)):
        idx = -i-1
        c = w[idx]
        if c >= best:
            best = c
        else:
            l = sorted(w[idx:])
            for j, ch in enumerate(l):
                if ch > c:
                    return w[:idx] + ch + ''.join(l[:j] + l[j+1:])
    return 'no answer'

n = input()
for i in range(n):
    print f(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

***MY solution in simple language: PYTHON 3***

check the word from reverse order and if a word greater than prev one  is found break the word into 2 part. after that sort the 2nd part and compare the last word of 1st part with 2nd part if greater word is found swap them.
at last join both part .

```
s="fedcbabcd"
s=list(s)
if (sorted(s,reverse=True))==s:
    print("no answer")
else:
    for i in range(len(s) - 1, 0, -1):
        if s[i] > s[i - 1]:
            lft = s[:i]
            rgt = s[i:]
            break

    rgt =(sorted(rgt))

    for i in range(len(rgt)):
        if lft[len(lft) - 1] < rgt[i]:
            t = lft[len(lft) - 1]
            lft[len(lft) - 1] = rgt[i]
            rgt[i] = t
            break


    print(''.join(lft+rgt))
```